# More declarative PHP: array conversion

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of class objects:

```
class Foo
{
    public $A;
    public $B;
    public $C;
}
```

I need a new array of C fields. Is there a way to convert the array **without** explicit loops? Hate that after C#.

```
// Explicit conversion:
foreach ($arr as $item)
{
    $Cs[] = $item->C;
}
```

Regards,

Comment: btw: in C# you can use linq, so you don't have to use explicit loops..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$Cs = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item->C;
}, $arr);
```

Comment: In PHP < 5.3 you can use named function with array_map('function_name', $arr);

Comment: Or `create_function()`, but in my opinion PHP5.3 should be mainstream nowadays.

Comment: Not a lambda syntax, but at least requires no external functions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [`get_object_vars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php).

```
$arr = get_object_vars(new Foo());
var_dump($arr); // should give Array(3) { "A"=>NULL, "B"=>NULL, "C"=>NULL }
```

Comment: Yep, but $arr is array of Foo, not a single instance. Also, I'll have to filter the resulting array from As and Bs.